# Host ASP.NET Web Application on local Machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, web-server

Please excuse me if this is very basic.

My query is about hosting a .net web application on a server. Say, I create a small web application and I deploy this application in my home machine (which has an IIS server).

How do I access this application from a remote location, some other computer in another network. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If your server has a public IP address then you should be able to access it as long as you open up your firewall for the service port (80 typically for http). If you have a router and NAT going on then you need to look into port forwarding.

Comment: If you don't use VS' Webserver Cassini but the IIS it's no problem to access it from a remote machine if it has network access to your local computer. You only have to [configure it in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I love basic questions, they're easy to answer!

First of all, determine your IP address.  That is the "public" IP address of your home router, which is the only address that is reachable over the Internet: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

If you're not paying your ISP extra, it is probably NOT a static address.  This means it might change from time to time, and if you want people to be able to connect to a server in your house, you need to provide a static DNS name for them to use to connect.  You can accomplish this using DynDns:  http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

Finally, you need to get incoming traffic from your router to your computer.  This involves configuring your router to "port forward" incoming Port 80 traffic to Port 80 on your PC.  For guides on how to configure port forwarding on your router: http://portforward.com/

Hope this helps, if you need any specific details post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static IP address on your connection, then you can connect by that, or point a domain name to that. You will need to configure your firewall to take requests on port 80 and send them to your machine which is referenced by internal ip (which will need to be static) or by UNC.

If you don't have a static IP, you can use a service like DynIP

Comment: Thanks John. But how do I determine if mine is a static or dynamic IP?

Comment: You can't port forward to a UNC path...

Comment: Surprising, my router uses the UNC value when you assign a rule to a machine. It comes with some predefined rules like web server, and it reads the UNCs itself. Netgear if you were wondering.

Comment: @Nishant - I think @pseudocoder has given you a very detailed explanation. I prefer to give clues and let you explorer. Thumbs up for @pseudocoder though!

Comment: @John: Thanks for the support, yeah companies should have to get a permit to write home router firmware.  Do you have to provide a SMB share name or is \\127.0.0.1 enough?  Just curious.

Comment: @Pseudocoder - You can do it by IP or by machine name, but I do it all by static IP as Apple Macs have a habit of picking up an IP first time, and then next time they are on the network they conflict with any machine that has has that IP reassigned to itslf. Keep all the machine in the high IP range and let the Apple Macs play in the low IP range. They are like brats.